# Combining concatenation with ORDER BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, concatenation, collation

I have troubles in combining concatenation with order by in Postgre (9.1.9).
Let's say, I have a table borders with 3 fields:

```
            Table "borders"
    Column     |         Type         | Modifiers 
---------------+----------------------+-----------
 country1      | character varying(4) | not null
 country2      | character varying(4) | not null
 length        | numeric              |
```

The first two fields are codes of the countries and the third one is the length of the border among those countries.
The primary key is defined on the first two fields.

I need to compose a select of a column that would have unique values for the whole table, in addition this column should be selected in decreasing order.
For this I concatenate the key fields with a separator character, otherwise two different rows might give same result, like (AB, C and A, BC).

So I run the following query:

```
select  country1||'_'||country2 from borders order by 1;
```

However in the result I see that the '_' character is omited from the sorting.
The results looks like this:

```
 ?column? 
----------
 A_CH
 A_CZ
 A_D
 AFG_IR
 AFG_PK
 AFG_TAD
 AFG_TJ
 AFG_TM
 AFG_UZB
 A_FL
 A_H
 A_I
 .
 .
```

You can see that the result is sorted as if '_' doesn't exists in the strings.

If I use a letter (say 'x') as a separator - the order is correct. But I must use some special character that doesn't appear in the country1 and country2 fields, to avoid contentions.

What should I do, in order to make the '_' character to be taken into account during the sorting.

---

#### EDIT

It turned out that the concatenation has nothing to do with the problem. The problem is that the order by simply ignores '_' character.

Comment: The `_` character may be relevant for sorting or not, [depending on your collation settings.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424033/debugging-postgresql-for-where-a-a/9424208#9424208)

Comment: Thanks, this is something I didn't knew, and learned it from the answers here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select country1 || '_' || country2 collate "C" as a
from borders
order by 1
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f482b/16)</kbd>**

Notes according to discussion in comments:

1.) `COLLATE "C"` applies in the `ORDER BY` clause as long as it references the expression in the `SELECT` clause by *positional parameter* or *alias*. If you repeat the expression in `ORDER BY` you also need to repeat the `COLLATE` clause if you want to affect the sort order accordingly.

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0049f/3)</kbd>**

2.) In collations where `_` does not influence the sort order, it is more efficient to use [fog's query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18706714/939860), even more so because that one makes use of the existing index (`primary key is defined on the first two fields`).
However, if `_` has an influence, one needs to sort on the combined expression:

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/50f30/2)</kbd>**

Query performance (tested in Postgres 9.2):
**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8122d/1)</kbd>**

[PostgreSQL Collation Support in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html)

Comment: Good, now the special character is taken into account, but it is sorted *after* the letters. Why is that, the ASCII code of '_' is less then the ASCII code of the letters?

Comment: Oh, I see, the characters are not sorted by the ASCII codes. They are sorted by the locale settings, and there letters goes before the special characters. Is there a way to sort the string by ASCII code of the characters?

Comment: @jutky I think better way is to go with fog solution

Comment: it doesn't catch all the cases, as I commented on his answer.

Comment: @jutky hm, ASCII code of underscore is 95 - http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/underscore-understrike-underbar-low-line-ascii-code-95.html so it's more than uppercase letters

Comment: Yes, you are correct, for upper case letters and underscore there wouldn't be a problem. But the ASCII code of underscore is less then lower case letters. As far as I found, in "C" locale this doesn't holds.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, thanks for lasting support :) Here is the official document that support you tests: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/locale.html

Comment: This would perform poorly in comparison, even more since, according to the question, the `primary key is defined on the first two fields`. This query could not use the index, while fog's query would.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter that's why I've said it's better to go with fog answer, my aim was to find why sort is not working and how to sort strings with '_'.

Comment: Well, the fact that there is no explanation for your solution (which turns out not to solve the problem while harming performance) adds to it. You write many good answers. This is not one of them.

Comment: well OP need to sort rows by country1_country2, not by country1, country2, as he said in comments to fog answer - _For example is you have two rows ("A B", "C") and ("A","B"). In your solution the second row would go before the first. But really, the string "A_B" should go after "A B_C"_ - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/50f30/2

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter and it the end, yes in theory it harms performance, I've checked the plans, thank you. But in the real life, would there be terrible difference? - I've checked this on 1000000 rows, and I can't see big difference at all - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/bd6c3/1. Anyway, thanks for tip about index. Have to go.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I don't understand the need for downvote. Even if the solution is not using indexes, at least is solves the problem. Unlike, fog's answer.

Comment: Removing my downvote due to your valid consideration concerning the potential influence of `'_'` on the sort order. But really, this needs to go into the answer, not just into comments! I ammended the answer and added some info to clarify while being at it.

Comment: The **performance** test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/bd6c3/1. has several limitations: 1) Only uses words with 1 or two char (only digits). 2) Test is under Postgres 9.1, which matches the Q but 9.2+ is more interesting due to covering indices. 3) It's not quite testing what you may think it does. `ORDER BY` repeats expression without `COLLATE`. Refer to the explanation I added to the answer above. Alternative test with 50k rows: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8122d/1

Comment: BTW, thank you guys for the link to sqlfiddle. I wasn't familiar with this useful resource.

Answer (score 8):

Just order by the two columns:

```
SELECT  country1||'_'||country2 FROM borders ORDER BY country1, country2;
```

Unless you use aggregates or windows, PostgreSQL allows to order by columns even if you don't include them in the SELECT list.

As suggested in another answer you can also change the collation of the combined column but, if you can, sorting on plain columns is faster, especially if you have an index on them.

Comment: I'f afraid this wouldn't catch all the cases. I'll check this further. Thanks for a simple suggestion.

Comment: The query is correct, and it will "catch all the cases". The bigger question is why is PostgreSql behaving that way.

Comment: This wouldn't work. For example is you have two rows ("A B", "C") and ("A","B"). In your solution the second row would go before the first. But really, the string "A_B" should go after "A B_C". ping @RobertCo.

Comment: @RobertCo `The bigger question is why is PostgreSql behaving that way.` This bothers me too.

Comment: @jutky What do you mean by "behaing that way"? The sort order is defined by the collation so the order of the rows should depend *only* on it.

Comment: @fog yes, this is something I didn't knew. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you do the following?

```
 select  country1||'_'||country2 from borders order by country1||'_'||country2
```

My knowledge on order by 1 only does an ordinal sort.   It won't do anything on concatenated columns.  Granted, I'm speaking from SQL Server knowledge, so let me know if I'm way off base.

**Edited:** Ok; just saw Parado's post as I posted mine.   Maybe you could create a view from this query (give it a column name) and then requery the view, order by that column? Or do the following:

```
select country_group from (
    select  country1||'_'||country2 as country_group from borders
    ) a
order by country_group
```

Comment: I've updated the question that if I use a letter as a separator the order is correct, so the problem is not in the order by `1`

Comment: Jutky, fair enough.   Try the edited suggestion as mentioned, and order however you'd like.  seems like @Roman's answer would work well too.